# Grid alignment in cs cart

Tags: grid-layout, cs-cart

In cs cart, while adding the top panel it is aligned as per the 16 or 12 grid. I need the customize it completely. and another one is how can we create the responsive website layout in cs cart

I tried to create the top panel for the website. In cs cart, it's complete layout is depends on grid. is there any other options to do it in customized option.